# After making a call programmatically, is it possible to send audio (speech) PCM data to remote phone?

Tags: android

any one can tell me that for android is it possible to send audio (speech) PCM data to another remote phone after making a phone call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot access or modify the in call audio stream in Android, so this is not possible through the public SDK

You will have to edit Android at a source level and build your own ROM image to do this.